# installing external 'library?' in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new to programming and wanted to check this program called primesieve. http://primesieve.org/
I have windows 7 with codeblocks ide.
I tried searching for a way to execute the program but couldnt find anything useful.
I have never added a library (is that called a library?) before so please help.
similar:
[Installing c library in codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424604/installing-c-library-in-codeblocks)
[cant install GMP library in codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340758/cant-install-gmp-library-in-codeblocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have received a `.h` (or `.hpp`) file and a `.lib` file, most likely with the names `primesieve.h` (or `primesieve.hpp`) and `primesieve.lib` (or something similar).

If you didn't receive those files in your download, then you may have to download the source. It should definitely have the `.h`/`.hpp` file, but it's possible you'll need to generate the `.lib` file yourself. There should be instructions for your system.

You need to include the `.h`/`.hpp` file in your source code. You need to link against the `.lib` file. This part is described in the articles you linked.